# Catching and handling errors with Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I'm trying to handle errors with Apollo in react gracefully. So the idea is whenever the user encounters an error of some sort (500 or anything else). I want to just show a message like 'something went wrong, please try again later'.

Upon the first render of the component this works fine (the error is present in data.error) but when I leave the route and the component is unmounted, it throws.

At the moment I cannot prevent it from throwing an error. I've tried pretty much everything in this thread: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/604#issuecomment-355648596

- `link-error`: Logs the errors, but doesn't prevent it from throwing
- `hoc`: Logs the errors, but doesn't prevent it from throwing
- `componentDidCatch`: Doesn't do anything
- `errorPolicy`: Prevents errors, but it means I also can't handle them anymore.

I always get the following stack:

`Unhandled error Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 500 Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 500
    at new ApolloError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/errors/ApolloError.js:36:28)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/core/QueryManager.js:287:41)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/core/QueryManager.js:668:17)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/core/QueryManager.js:667:18)
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/core/QueryManager.js:662:22)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/core/QueryManager.js:236:31)
    at <anonymous>`

For reference:
- apollo-client: 2.2.5
- react-apollo: 2.0.4

Comment: What do you mean by throwing the error? Does your app crash?

Comment: Yep, @Locco0_0, it crashes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As described here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/604#issuecomment-313288541):

> I believe the way to "handle" the error when using the graphql HOC is
>   to simply **check data.errors inside the component**. There's a check
>   inside apollo-client that throws if data.errors isn't accessed.

The whole issue on GitHub where this comment was made has a very interesting discussion about the how's and why's. Most of the proposed solutions didn't work for me, especially the `componentDidCatch`, which, IMHO, was the cleanest alternative.

I could get over it touching the `this.props.data.error`, but I'm definitely not happy with it.

**Edit**

I've just noticed that you mentioned that the errors where happening when the component was unmounting... and well, [it seems to be fixed on 2.1.0-beta.3](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2258#issuecomment-368629017). :-)

Comment: Correct, the beta fixed it!